# Convert 24-hour time to 12-hour time from Forms using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently using Forms to collect data for a specific time. Problem is, it's coming back in a 24-hour format although it was asked in a 12-hour format. (i.e., 1:00 PM on form shows 13:00 in Logger event) Is there a way to convert from 24-hour back to 12-hour? The code I'm using is below.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var submissionSSKey = 'WorkSheet ID';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var PUStartTime = e.response.getItemResponses()[4].getResponse(); //Needs to be in 12-hour
  var PUEndTime = e.response.getItemResponses()[5].getResponse(); //Needs to be in 12-hour

  var joinedTimes = (PUStartTime + " - " + PUEndTime); //This is why I need 12-hour times

  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 1).setValues([[joinedTimes]]);
}
```

Comment: just get the value of the response and if it's bigger than 12 make sure to subtract 12 from it.

Comment: @IdoGreen Using Logger.log(PUEndTime - 12) results in: [14-10-01 10:51:07:788 MST] NaN. Might be because 13:00 isn't the same as 13.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final version of how I am accomplishing this. The time layout can be changed using the examples from here: [Date and Time Preference reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var submissionSSKey = 'WorkSheet ID';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Get current time
  var d = new Date();

  var PUStartTime = e.response.getItemResponses()[4].getResponse();
     var split = PUStartTime.split(":"); //Split the time submitted from user on Forms
        var part1 = split[0];
        var part2 = split[1];
          d.setHours(part1) //Set the current hour to user submitted hours
          d.setMinutes(part2) //Set the current minute to user submitted minutes
  //Format the time to how we want it
  var startTime = Utilities.formatDate(d, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "h:mm a");


  var PUEndTime = e.response.getItemResponses()[5].getResponse();
    var split = PUEndTime.split(":"); //Split the time submitted from user on Forms
        var part1 = split[0];
        var part2 = split[1];
          d.setHours(part1) //Set the current hour to user submitted hours
          d.setMinutes(part2) //Set the current minute to user submitted minutes
  //Format the time to how we want it
  var endTime = Utilities.formatDate(d, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "h:mm a");

  //Joining those new 12-hour times together
  var joinedTimes = (startTime + " - " + endTime); 

  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 1).setValues([[joinedTimes]]);
}
```

Comment: Hard coding time zone with GMT+XX values is dangerous if your country uses daylight savings,the time value will be shifted in winter vs summer. Prefer using a string country/state value that fits your needs as this will automatically adapt to daylight savings.

Comment: Arizona (where I am and where the form will be used) doesn't observe daylight savings time so I lucked out there.

Comment: Oh lucky man :-) , one problem you don't have!!! Btw, it's always summer in Arizona I  guess?

Comment: @Sergeinsas I changed the code a bit. It should work with any time zone now. I guess the Arizona legislature thought it was always summer...

Answer (score 4):

If your PUEndTime variable is in the date format,

maybe try using the formatDate() utility?

[Google Documentation - Format Date](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

```
var endTime = Utilities.formatDate(PUEndTime, "GMT", "hh:mm a");
```

h = Hour in am/pm (1-12)

a = Am/pm marker

[Date and Time patterns reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I'm getting an "Execution failed: Cannot find method formatDate(string,string,string)" in the execution log.

Comment: I'm guessing it's one of those error msg that is at least slightly wrong, because there is a formatDate method.  Maybe it doesn't like the PUEndTime variable after all?  Just to check that line of code, you could replace PUEndTime with `new Date()` like in the example in the documentation and see what happens.

Comment: use `var endTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(PUEndTime), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "hh:mm a");`

Comment: @Sergeinsas That seemed to do it. It's converting just fine except for the fact that when it converts for example, 13:00 (01:00 PM) it's showing as 05:00 PM. Something relating to the Time Zone. Any ideas on why that would happen?

Comment: Check the form time zone, the script time zone and the spreadsheet timezone settings, all must be set to the same value.

Comment: @Sergeinsas The timezone for the script is "America/Phoenix" but I'm not totally sure how to check the Forms' timezone.

Comment: is the script embedded in some document ? sorry but I'm not the "answerer" here... just a commenter ;-)) just wanted to drop a hint...if you want you can also hard code the timezone instead of using session.getScriptTimeZone.

Comment: It's actually linked to the Forms itself. I'll play around with hard coding it and post the solution when I get it.